# SMS API issue with CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, sms

Hi guys Please someone to help me fix an issue with an sms API. Here is the entire code given by the sms API provider:

I don't know what is wrong and I don't know how to fix the 415 issue. The API provider doens't give coding support

```
/* 
    *:: How to generate Token in PHP using our Restful API
    */ 
       "https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/gettoken/username/MYUSERNAME/password/MYPASSWORD",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "GET",
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
    /* 
    *::: How to send sms with your generated Token
    */
    
     "https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/sms/send",
      CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER    => true,
      CURLOPT_ENCODING          => "",
      CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS         => 10,
      CURLOPT_TIMEOUT           => 30,
      CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION      => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
      CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST     => "POST",
      CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS        => "{\"from\":\"Sender Name\",\"to\":[\"16813000014\",\"16813000014\"],\"type\":\"Text\",\"content\":\"Sample SMS Content To Be Sent\"}",
      CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER        => array(
                                    "token : USER TOKEN GENERATED FROM GET TOKEN API",
                                    "content-type: application/json"
                                ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    
    if ($err) {
      echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    } else {
      echo $response;
    }
```

And here is the code I developped:

```
  $curl=curl_init("https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/gettoken/username/xxxxx/password/xxxxx");
  curl_setopt_array($curl,[
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER  => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING        => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS       => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT         => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION    => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST   => "GET",
]);

$response = curl_exec($curl);
$err = curl_error($curl);

$ch = curl_init("https://restapi.bulksmsonline.com/rest/api/v1/sms/send");
$field = array('from'=>'From me', 'to'=>'237668426982', 'type'=>'Text', 'content'=>'message');
$head = array('token'=>'$response', 'content-type'=>'application/json');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING,"" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS,10 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,30 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION,CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST,'POST' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$field );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,$head );
$output = curl_exec($ch);      

$err = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
  echo $output;
}
```

Here is the response displayed:

```
{"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.13","title":"Unsupported Media Type","status":415,"traceId":"|54541add-41130078fe10574f."}
```

Please help me to fix that.
Thks

Comment: You need to encode your field data as JSON. Use json_encode() to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your post fields and headers as per the API provider's sample. The post fields should be JSON string, not an array. The headers array is not an associative array, it is an array of strings.

```php
$headers = ["token: {$response}", "content-type: application/json"];
$fields = ['from' => 'From me', 'to' => ['237668426982'], 'type' => 'Text', 'content' => 'message'];
$postFields = json_encode($fields);
```

And then use them for the cURL request,

```php
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postFields);
```

On another note, in your code, you have this `'token'=>'$response'`, a PHP variable inside single quotes; this will not work. If the variable has a string literal, then you do not need the quotes at all. If you have to use quotes, then use variables inside double quotes.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thks. I made changes and I receive this:  {"errors":{"to":["Error converting value \"237668426982\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'to', line 1, position 37."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|e88d5cb0-4727c87b90704ca0."}

Comment: @ Sohel Aman  ```{"errors":{"to":["Error converting value \"237668426982\" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]'. Path 'to', line 1, position 37."]},"type":"https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1","title":"One or more validation errors occurred.","status":400,"traceId":"|e88d5cb0-4727c87b90704ca0."}```

Comment: Ah, the `to` field is supposed to be an array. Change `'to'=>'237668426982'` to `'to'=>['237668426982']` in your fields array.

Comment: Another error. I'm really tired. tks for all. {"Message":"Some error occured while executing your request!","Detail":"IDX12709: CanReadToken() returned false. JWT is not well formed: '[PII is hidden. For more details, see https://aka.ms/IdentityModel/PII.]'.\nThe token needs to be in JWS or JWE Compact Serialization Format. (JWS): 'EncodedHeader.EndcodedPayload.EncodedSignature'. (JWE): 'EncodedProtectedHeader.EncodedEncryptedKey.EncodedInitializationVector.EncodedCiphertext.EncodedAuthenticationTag'.","Token":null,"IP":"172.69.68.196","StackTrace":"